# Separating column value after using CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Hi there and thanks in advance. I'm a newbie.. learning by trial and error.

I need to:
1. Merge 2 columns into one from db 1 - **DONE**
   "SELECT CONCAT(lName, fName) AS name FROM `dir`"
   "name" column looks like this: DubaiPeter L.

2. Separate the value(s) by a comma and space
   to look like this: Dubai, Peter L.

I'm sure this is super easy and I just don't know where to look.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php

Comment: Why not "merge" a comma and a space (as a literal value) between `lName` and `fName`? If you need the value without the comma, then return two separate expressions in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT CONCAT(lName, ', ', fName) AS name FROM dir`

Comment: Yep, eventually found that - thank you! :) 
Also solved next problem (in case anyone else comes across this) to enter that one value (lName, fName) into a new column:

1. Created new column "name"

Comment: 2. UPDATE `dir` SET name = CONCAT(lName, ', ', fName)

Comment: Remember to add it as correct answer if possible. Thanks